# PHP Hbase Thrift client returns array instead of TRowResult

Tags: php, hbase, thrift

We are using the Thrift client to access Hbase from PHP. Hbase version is hbase-0.90.4-cdh3u3.

My problem (well, it's more like a doubt) is that the Thrift API is supposed to return `TRowResult` for a number of methods, for example: `scannerGet`, `getRowWithColumns`... Instead, it returns an array with a single `TRowResult` instance.

Does anyone know why is that? Is there any case when these methods - that typically are supposed to return a single row or none - return more than one `TRowResult` instances? Can I simply pop this one row in my wrapper class and return it instead of returning the array (or null if there's empty array)?

The .thrift documentation is pretty clear about what is supposed to be returned:

```
/** 
 * Get the specified columns for the specified table and row at the latest
 * timestamp. Returns an empty list if the row does not exist.
 * 
 * @return TRowResult containing the row and map of columns to TCells
 */
list<TRowResult> getRowWithColumns(
```

[...]

```
/**
 * Returns the scanner's current row value and advances to the next
 * row in the table.  When there are no more rows in the table, or a key
 * greater-than-or-equal-to the scanner's specified stopRow is reached,
 * an empty list is returned.
 *
 * @return a TRowResult containing the current row and a map of the columns to TCells.
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgument if ScannerID is invalid
 *
 * @throws NotFound when the scanner reaches the end
 */
list<TRowResult> scannerGet(
```

(Although `@throws NotFound` is obsolete)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are getRows() and scannerGetList() methods, which returns array of TRowResult objects.
I used hbase from cdh3u4, don't know if theese methods exists in cdh3u3.
BTW, cdh4 should already containn hbase 0.92 and support scan filters ;)

Comment: My question is more like, why methods that are *supposed* to return only one row return an array instead of just the array. Can I always assume that they will return zero or one rows?

Comment: Can't tell for sure, maybe to unify retuned results. I use wrapper for getRow() function, that returns TRowResult object (or null).

Comment: I will do the same, I jsut wanted to know if there could be any unexpected cases. Thanks! :)